# git push -u origin main not responding and not working

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I created a React app project on Visual Studio and when I try to push it to GitHub it doesn't do anything.

I wrote the following lines one by one:

```bash
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/alperenyazmaci/asd.git
git push -u origin main
```

The last push command is not giving any results, not even errors.
See the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: may be you can share some screenshots ?

Comment: Do `git remote -v` to see what your remotes are, you probably need to add a 'origin' remote.

Comment: Maybe your problem's cause is that you didn't log in correctly by using the terminal. I am not sure but the project you want to contribute to is private. If you want to try it, could you set the origin remote like **https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/username/reponame.git**

Comment: One problem is that you should not be using an `https` URL to talk to a GitHub remote.

Comment: Also please do not post pictures of text.

Comment: Your image-of-text shows a perfectly normal `git push` that finished sending everything to `origin`. If you haven't gotten a prompt back, your own Git is now waiting for the Git software over *at* origin to acknowledge successful receipt of all the commits (or, if that other Git software chooses to reject them, a rejection message from them). Since you're pushing to GitHub specifically, you should check to see if GitHub is operating correctly and if your network connection to them is functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like it works. There are commits to the `main` branch in your repo at around the time you asked the question. (The first commit isn't 'First commit', but I'm not sure you posted real commands).

[image]